# turn off zoom achart engine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

AchartEngine have two ways to zoom chart. First is by the "button" and second by the "fingers". Is there a way to disable one of them? I don't want to zoom by "fingers". Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use XYMultipleSeriesRenderer methods to enable or disable zooming

```
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
mRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
```

also see this

http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/tools/class-use/ZoomListener.html#org.achartengine